# ¿Por que se me sobreescriben los datos en los registros del archivo binario?

Tags: c

realice un funcion que consiste en rellenar un archivo binario, luego mostrar esos datos por pantalla y despues presentarle al usuario un menu ABM, pero me encuentro con el problema de que los datos ingresados en el archivo se sobreescriben, o eso entiendo yo, dejo el codigo de las funciones que competerían al problema.

```
void main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("gestion.dat", "r+b");
    t_gestion gestion;
    crear_arch();

    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        cargar_reg(&gestion, fp);
    }

    printf("Legajo \t Apellido \t Nombre \t Cargo\n");
    fseek(fp,sizeof(t_gestion),SEEK_SET);
    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        mostrar(gestion, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

funciones:

```
void cargar_reg(t_gestion *gestion, FILE *fp){
    printf("Ingrese el legajo: ");
    scanf("%i", &(*gestion).legajo);
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    printf("Ingrese el apellido: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets((*gestion).apellido);

    printf("Ingrese el nombre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets((*gestion).nombre);

    printf("Ingrese el cargo: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets((*gestion).cargo);

    printf("Ingrese el permiso(valor del 1 al 5): ");
    scanf("%i", &(*gestion).permiso);
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    printf("Ingrese el estado(1 - activo | 0 - inactivo): ");
    scanf("%i", &(*gestion).activo);
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    fwrite(gestion,sizeof(t_gestion),1,fp);
}

void mostrar(t_gestion gestion, FILE *fp){
    fread(&gestion,sizeof(t_gestion),1,fp);
    if(gestion.activo == 1){
        printf("%i\t", gestion.legajo);
        printf("%s\t\t", gestion.apellido);
        printf("%s\t\t", gestion.nombre);
        printf("%s\n", gestion.cargo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que cada llamada a `cargar_reg` guarda los datos en la misma variable `gestion`. Por eso es que se sobreescriben los datos.

```
t_gestion gestion;

...

for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
    cargar_reg(&gestion, fp);
}
```

Convierte la variable en un arreglo y guarda los datos en diferentes posiciones de él:

```
t_gestion gestion[MAX];

...

for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
    cargar_reg(&gestion[i], fp);
}
```

---

Por cierto, hay una forma más fácil de acceder a los campos de un puntero. Mediante el operador [`->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Member_access_through_pointer).

Por ejemplo, en lugar de:

```
(*gestion).apellido
```

Escribe:

```
gestion->apellido
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias enserio!! aplicare la recomendacion para acceder a los campos, gracias!!